# Which version of Nhibernate works with .NET 6 & Visual Studio 2022?

Tags: .net, nhibernate, .net-6.0, visual-studio-2022

we are upgrading our software which requires .NET 6 & Visual Studio 2022.

Need to know which version of NHibernate works with .NET 6 & Visual Studio 2022

Tried google research but couldn't find and also read articles but no luck. Need help to know version on NHibernate.

Comment: .NET 6 is .NET *Core* 6, so anything that targets .NET Standard 2.0 or .NET Core will work. That's all versions since 5.1.0

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the [latest version](https://www.nuget.org/packages/NHibernate) (5.5) is the one for you.

Answer (score 0):

All versions since 5.1.0 will work but it's better to use 5.4.0 or above, the first one to target .NET 6 explicitly. .NET 6 is .NET *Core* 6 and can use packages that target .NET Standard or .NET Core.

The earliest version that targeted .NET Standard was [5.1.0](https://www.nuget.org/packages/NHibernate/5.1.0), back in 2018. An explicit target for .NET 6 was added in [5.4.0](https://www.nuget.org/packages/NHibernate/5.4.0), in 2022. The latest version at this point is 5.5.0, released one month ago.